# The null set as the underlying set of a relation structure

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, equivalence-relations

Can the null-set underly a relation structure?  Can it underly a well-order?  If so, would such a well-order have order-type $0$?  (Can one even have an order-type of $0$?)

My motivation for this question is distantly but completely related to an earlier posting I made re a problem that's been bugging me this whole day: I've been trying to show that for any set $W$ of well-orders, there is a well-order $(A, X)$ such that for all $(B, Y) \in W, \exists a \in A$ such that $(B, Y) \cong I_a$, where $I_a$ is the initial segment of $(A, X)$ up to $a$.

A wise user on here showed me that one could form the set $W'/R$, where $W'$ is the set of all (in his qualifying words, "not necessarily proper") initial segments in $W$, and $R$ is order-isomorphism.  But my main fear is that very qualification: I know that $W'/R$ is itself well-ordered by order-type comparison.  I'm just worried that $W'/R$ is *only* just as "large" as the largest order-type in $W'$, because $W'/R$ must be "larger" than $W'$ in order for *everything* in $W$ to be isomorphic to a *proper* initial segment of $W'/R$.  If $0$ is indeed an order-type, then $W'/R$ would be "+1 larger" than $W$, which is what we need, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: In model theory, the underlying set is by tradition always non-empty.

Comment: @AndréNicolas On the other hand, an ordinal number is the order type of a well-ordered set, and $0$ is an ordinal number, so $0$ is an order type. Likewise, $0$ is a cardinal number, although in model theory the models of equality theory are the nonempty sets.

Comment: @bof So would that be yes, bof?

Comment: Yes, $0$ is an ordinal, so it's an order type. Don't really understand why that matters to you. If your well-ordered set is infinite, adding another element at the **bottom** isn't going to make it any bigger. (E.g. the positive integers and the nonnegative integers.) On the other hand, what's to stop you from taking some new element--anything in the world that's not already there--and adding it at the **top** where it will do some good?

Comment: @bof Thanks for your responses.  However, I'm confused as to how the position of the element-to-be-added we're talking about affects the "size" of the set.  My idea was that you just map downward to establish the isomorphisms.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm just being obtuse.

Comment: The set $N$ of positive integers in the natural order, $1\lt2\lt3\dots$, is a well-ordered set. Add $0$ at the bottom, you get the nonnegative integers in their natural order: $0\lt1\lt2\dots$, which is **isomorphic** to $N$, and does **not** have a proper initial segment isomorphic to $N$. However, if you add a new element, call it $\omega$, at the top, you get $0\lt1\lt2\lt\dots\lt\omega$, which **does** have a proper initial segment isomorphic to $N$. The order type of $N$ is called $\omega$, and it's a fact that $1+\omega=\omega<\omega+1$; ordinal addition is not commutative.

Comment: @bof Aha! I see now...thanks a ton for the illumination (especially the concrete example)!  Now I'm just thinking about how one defines such an $\omega$ in a way that is consistent with the ordering on $W'/R$. ADDENDUM: Oh wait...I guess it really could be anything, right? :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12753/discussion-between-mike-and-bof)